# Pendulum with angular velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, differential

I have another pendulum problem again but this time it's with angular velocity. My question is:

If a pendulum is initially at its unstable equilibrium position, then how large an initial angular velocity is necessary for the pendulum to go completely around?

So basically we need to find a $\theta$ that will spin this pendulum around for 1 full period $T$. I am assuming `unstable equilibrium position` means that it is inverted therefore a slight push will send it out of the equilibrium position. I just don't understand how I would calculate something like that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no friction, energy is conserved.  Any velocity from the unstable equilibrium is enough to spin it all the way around.

Comment: is there no mathematics behind this?

Comment: You don't need any.  Once you have more total energy than the situation of the pendulum vertically upward and motionless, it will never turn around.  If it were to turn around, both the PE and KE would be less than the original situation.  Given a starting velocity, you can solve the equations to determine the position as  function of time, but that is not required to answer the original question.